# When to use void[] vs. ubyte[] in D

Tags: arrays, d

Is there a general rule as to when I should use `void[]` instead of `ubyte[]`? Is either preferred?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`void[]` for data that may contain pointers, `byte[]` for data that's actually *just* data, like network buffers or files. (I realize Phobos is inconsistent on this)

The reasoning is that the GC scans `void[]`s for pointers, but not `ubyte[]`s.

Comment: Note that this is what type the memory is allocated as rather than the type of the references you have to it.

Comment: I guess your "I realize Phobos is inconsistent on this" pretty much answered any follow-up questions I had. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

Check out this discussion:

http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/learn/272.html